# Efficient way to not delete gameobject reference of singleton after scene reload

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I have a singleton class and everytime I reload a scene the object reference I store in variable is destroyed

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
     private void Awake()
     {
         if (instance == null)
         {
             instance = this;
         }
         else
         {
             Destroy(this.gameObject);
         }
         DontDestroyOnLoad(this);

         Debug.Log("Scene reloaded");
    }


    void Start()
    {
        shapeSpawnerGO = GameObject.Find("SpawnShapesObj");
        scoreGO = GameObject.Find("ScoreText");
        lifeGo = GameObject.Find("LifeText");
    }

    public bool RedShapeStatus(int rcv_RedShapeIndex)
    {
        if (shapeSpawnerGO == null)
        {
            shapeSpawnerGO = GameObject.Find("SpawnShapesObj");
        }
        return shapeSpawnerGO.GetComponent<ShapeSpawnerChild>().listofRedShape[rcv_RedShapeIndex].activeSelf;     
    }
}
```

What I've done is check if shapeSpawnerGO is null then reference again the gameobject. And I think this is not efficient. Is there other way to solve this issue?

Comment: Is SpawnShapesObj at DontDestroy ? If not you need find again actually.

Comment: What happens if `instance == this`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certainly other ways to accomplish this, but my official answer is "You're already doing it an acceptable way."  You specifically said this:

> "What I've done is check if shapeSpawnerGO is null then reference
>   again the gameobject. And I think this is not efficient. Is there
>   other way to solve this issue?"

You said the only time your code reinitializes the variables is whenever the scene reloads.That operation time doesn't even matter.  You're literally talking about optimizing something completely irrelevant.  Reinitializing scene data during a reload is what normal scene loading is all about.

The only exception to this would be if your idea of a scene reload is something you're doing every few seconds.  If you're talking about the normal idea of a scene reload where you load the game scene once and then proceed to run the game for many minutes before a new scene reloads, then there's no reason to be worried about this code doing its normal initialization behavior.